Invalid format for indirect buffer's UAV
I want to create a UAV for an indirect draw buffer, but I get this error:
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateUnorderedAccessView: The Format (0, UNKNOWN) cannot be used when creating a typed View of a Buffer. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #2097343: CREATEUNORDEREDACCESSVIEW_INVALIDFORMAT]

Code:
struct DrawIndexedIndirectCommand
{
    std::uint32_t count;
    std::uint32_t instanceCount;
    std::uint32_t firstIndex;
    std::uint32_t baseVertex;
    std::uint32_t baseInstance;
};

const std::uint32_t structSize = sizeof(DrawIndexedIndirectCommand);
const std::uint32_t count = 1;

D3D11_BUFFER_DESC desc{};
desc.ByteWidth = structSize * count;
desc.StructureByteStride = structSize;
desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS;
desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
desc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_DRAWINDIRECT_ARGS;

ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> buffer;
HRESULT result = device->CreateBuffer(&desc, nullptr, &buffer);
ALWAYS_ASSERT(result >= 0 && "CreateBuffer");

D3D11_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC uavDesc = {};
uavDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
uavDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
uavDesc.Buffer.FirstElement = 0;
uavDesc.Buffer.NumElements = count;

ComPtr<ID3D11UnorderedAccessView> uav;
result = device->CreateUnorderedAccessView(buffer.Get(), &uavDesc, &uav);
ALWAYS_ASSERT(result >= 0 && "CreateUnorderedAccessView");

Shader:
struct DrawIndexedIndirectCommand
{
    uint count;
    uint instanceCount;
    uint firstIndex;
    uint baseVertex;
    uint baseInstance;
};

RWStructuredBuffer<DrawIndexedIndirectCommand> indirectBuffer : register(u0);

...

What format should I use? I guess it'd work with D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_STRUCTURED flag, but a resource cannot created with both D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_DRAWINDIRECT_ARGS and D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_STRUCTURED.
Is it possible to do it this way? If yes, how can I fix it? If not, what's the alternative way to write into this buffer from the shader?
